# SQL Query To Select Distinct Value

Tags: sql, distinct

I've got a table **tbl_mail** with the following structure:

```
tbl_mail
____________
mail_from_user_id
mail_to_user_id
```

I want to find all people with whom I once had a conversation. I could write to them or the could write to me, and I need to know the id number of the opponent.  Let's say I've got id number 1.

```
tbl_mail
___________
mail_from_user_id | mail_to_user_id
------------------------------------
1                 | 2
1                 | 3
4                 | 1
```

In the example above I wrote to 2 different people (id`s - 2 & 3), and another person wrote to me ( number 4 ).
How can I find out all people I interacted with (except for myself).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT a.mail_from_user_id AS user
  FROM TBL_MAIL a
 WHERE a.mail_to_user_id = 1
UNION 
SELECT b.mail_to_user_id AS user
  FROM TBL_MAIL b
 WHERE b.mail_from_user_id = 1
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates.  `UNION ALL` would not, and be faster for it.

Comment: It may be interesting to know if 1-2 and 2-1 is a duplicate for Denis purposes given the fact that in your SELECT this case would not be detected.

Comment: @Doliveras: The OP wants a list of all people, and it's only logical to assume that there should not be duplicates, but that must have been obvious. For that purpose, I believe, 1-2 and 2-1 should be considered duplicates, but this answer will successfully eliminate them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select mail_to_user_id as mailid from tbl_mail where mail_from_user_id=1
     union 
    select mail_from_user_id as mailid from tbl_mail where mail_to_user_id=1
```

Where 1 is your id. Replace it with desired id.

Comment: The DISTINCT, besides the derived table/inline view, is unnecessary because of using `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack:

Select idx from
(Select mail_from_user_id as idx from tbl_mail where mail_to_user_id = 1 group by mail_from_user_id
Union
Select mail_to_user_id as idx from tbl_mail where mail_from_user_id = 1 group by mail_to_user_id)
group by idx

Comment: Just for an exercise, please click on `edit` to edit your answer, highlight the part that represents the script and either press `Ctrl+K` or click `{ }`. The preview will show you the result and you will see for yourself how much more presentable your answer can be. And after you post the edit you'll even earn a badge. :)